# How do i get the values of wrapped arrays in php?

Tags: php

The $wrap array is a wrapped data and options array.  How can I echo the array values of $options or $data calling the $wrap array variable?

```
$wrap = array($data, $options);

$data = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
$options = array('a', 'b', "key" => "c", 'd', 'e');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$wrap = array($data, $options);` is equivalent to `$wrap = array(0=>$data, 1=>$options);`.
I.e. via `$wrap[1]` you get the same array as $option thus $option['key'] => $wrap[1]['key']

E.g.

```
<?php
$data = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
$options = array('a', 'b', "key" => "c", 'd', 'e');
$wrap = array($data, $options);
echo $wrap[1]['key'];
```

But you might want to use an associative index for $wrap to increase readability

```
<?php
$data = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
$options = array('a', 'b', "key" => "c", 'd', 'e');
$wrap = array('data'=>$data, 'opts'=>$options);
echo $wrap['opts']['key'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $wrap[0][0]; //outputs 1
echo $wrap[1]['key']; //outputs c
```

extremely useful reading: http://php.net/types.array